# unable to connect to openfire server

Tags: openfire

I just downloaded the openfire server and installed on my laptop.
Started the server

[image]

Server is running perfectly.

[image]

But not getting any response  when I am tyring to connect to server by this http://kh9144:9876/

what would be the reason ?

Comment: This port is for xmpp client

Comment: what does it mean ?
how can i connect to server and send message ?

Comment: change that port to the default one 5222, then connect using an xmpp client using you jabberId and password

Comment: @Kassav . I tried with spark client but It failed in account creation and login. What is causing that problem ?

Comment: @TirupatiRao did you found any solution?